# How can you return multiple items with a single query in Firebase?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, nosql

I've never worked with a NoSQL database before so I'm a little confused as to how they work. I'm trying to create a database of attraction in a city. I have a key and a value for each city. Under each city I want to have a list of attractions.

Problem is each of attractions needs its own key. If I give each attraction its own key, then how can I return all of the attractions for a city using a single query? Wouldn't I need to do run a query for every key to get every value?

I'm basically trying to figure out how to get my database set-up so that I can run a query on `London` and get the three items listed under it.

Comment: `ref.child("London").addChildEventListener(...`

Comment: So that would create a method called `onDataChange` and in that I would uses `dataSnapshot.getValue()` to return a map of all the items. But how do I then get the individual items without knowing what all of their keys are.

Comment: A `ChildEventListener` has `onChildAdded`, which fires for each **child** node under the location. Try it or take the [Firebase codelab for Android](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/firebase-android/), which teaches this and much more.

Comment: Also posted on https://www.reddit.com/r/Firebase/comments/65k3gd/how_can_you_return_all_the_children_and/

Answer (score 1):

First you have to create a POJO(Plain Old Java Object) for your Attraction which contains the description, etc. The variables need to be consistent with what the key in the database is:

```
@IgnoreExtraProperties
public class Attraction{
    String name, description1, descrition2;
    //Other variables/keys

    String getName(){
        return this.name;
    }

    void setName(String name){
        this.name = name;
    }

    //Other getter/setter methods
    public Attraction(){}
}
```

Next you would have your database structure like this:

```
City
---Attraction Name
------Description 1
------Description 2
```

Then you could simply perform the query with:

```
DatabaseReference ref = databaseReference.child("City").child("London");
```

Then couple it with a listener to get the attractions and store it in a list:

```
List<Attraction> attractions = new ArrayList<>();
ref.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        for(DataSnapshot val : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
            Attraction attraction = val.getValue(Attraction.class);
            attraction.setName(val.getKey()); //This is because the key is the attraction name based on the structure
            attractions.add(attraction));
        }
        //After getting all of them in a list, return them
        return attractions; //use this if you want to return them as a List Object
        return attractions.toArray(new Attraction[attractions.size()]); //use this if you want to return it as an array
    }
    @Override
    public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError) {

    }
})
```

Let me know if this helps you.

Comment: Wait so you're telling me that would return all of the attractions listed under London? I'm storing these to a map so how could I access the individual attractions?

Comment: To access them individually, traverse the List

Comment: In your example, how are you accessing all the values if you don't know all of their keys? I see that you basically looping for the size of the snapshot but then how do you access the actual values inside the map?

Comment: Also who can you use a for loop on a `dataSnapshot`? I just tried that and it's giving me an error saying that foreach is not applicable.

Comment: Could you add more details on what specific output would you need? An output with the keys that you need

Comment: Sure, I've updated my question to show what a finished list would look like. Basically I would be given the city and then I would want to get each attraction along with the descriptions for each one. So I would like to be able to return an array of tuples where each tuple has `attractionName`, `attractionDescription1`, `attractionDescription2`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/141783/discussion-between-kurt-acosta-and-natasha-alexandrov).